# Trouble assigning the Container property

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, bootstrap-popover

I am using bootstrap popover in  a page with scrollbar. When i scroll my screen, the popover just goes up on the screen. Please find below image.

My popover code:

```
 <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="" class="questionIcon" data-placement="top">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-3x" style="color:#70C53B"></i>
    </a>
```

I tried to use `container: '.questionIcon'` while i initialize the popover but it just changes the style of popover and make it a link and mess up the navigation. How can i make my popover attached to triggering icon ?

[image]

Comment: Possibly a bootstrap popover isn't the best solution for this. Rather a custom solution with an absolutely positioned element might work better for you.

Comment: @BillyMoat - I was able to do the custom solution. How could i make my popover visible on top of all the content ? Tried every possible way but no luck. how can i just ignore the z-index of all the element in the back and keep the popover on top ?

Comment: I'd probably recommend copying the code used for a bootstrap modal with regards to z-index etc.